# Toshiba Satellite l755 overheats

Tags: power-management

I really want to use the new unity and the integration options, i'm running a toshiba satellite l755-s5349, but, it keeps my laptop on a very high temperature, with very high peaks specially when i open the dash, it gets really hot, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sort of thing is usually driven by the BIOS/ACPI. Install `fwts` and run the full test suite to see how well it's doing, your ACPI tables might require a bit of surgery...

Comment: this the summary of the test, is this to bad? using gnome, i don't get any problem with temp
440 passed, 32 failed, 7 warnings, 1 aborted, 76 skipped, 4 info only.
Critical failures: 1
02118 summary          klog test, at 1 log line: 144
02119 summary           "CRITICAL Kernel message: [    0.791928]  pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_ERROR), returned control mask: 0x1d"
there is more

Comment: pastebin it please

Comment: sorry to be a newby but it's too long to paste here, how can i send the log to you??

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. Use this site, http://pastebin.com/, for your log paste and add the URL here. Thanks.

Comment: this is the link http://pastebin.com/4tbAvvHG . thanks for your help and time.

Comment: could mean anything the fact that i have my processor set to 'on demand' with the temp peaks?

Comment: Nope, that's normal. The bulk of the heat generated from a laptop comes mostly from the CPU and then the GPU. If you're using OS drivers for the GPU, that will significantly contribute to your net heat as the opensource drivers are just lacking in comprehensive power management code. Many vendors consider this proprietary and will never release it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and type

```
sudo apt-get install uswsusp laptop-mode-tools
```

This should somewhat solve the problem.

Comment: using unity 2d kind of solve the problem, that remove the heat peaks, but that is no the idea, probably the visual effects are responsible for the heating? is that normal?? should i be worried with that?

Comment: It could be the visual effects. Try `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`. This is a powerful tool that allows you to tweak the system (lower the graphic settings). If your fan spins really fast, or there is too much heat generated, then it could be a kernel/driver problem.

Comment: the fan doesn't seems to be spinning at max speed, the problem is, i'm monitoring the temp with psensor, before upgrade my temp with gnome 3 was about 48 C in  normal work, now with unity normally in 49 C but almost anything i do the temp goes 55 C or 57 C and if i open the dash it passes the 60 C and stays that way until i close the dash , any suggestions? any other hardware where you had tested this??

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the restricted drivers? Usually that solves all overheating issues with laptops as well as power consumption issues.